# Deriving FTC from the generalized Stokes.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential

How do I derive the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus from the generalized Stokes theorem?

Comment: I mean, $[a,b]$ is an oriented manifold with boundary $\partial [a,b]=a-b$ where I mean $a-b$ as a symbol of the orientation, and the exterior derivative is just the normal derivative, $df=f'(x)\,dx$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. Note that $[a,b]$ is a 1-dimensional manifold with boundary = $\{a,b\}$. Stokes theorem says $\int_{\partial[a,b]}f=\int_{[a,b]}df$. LHS is just $f(b)-f(a)$ (the minus sign is due to the induced orientaion), and RHs is $\int_a^bf'(x)dx$.

Comment: I cannot understand how the LHS and RHs becomes the FTC.

Comment: LHS is an integral of a $0$ form on a $0$ dimensional manifold, which is exactly the sum of the values of the function at all points, considering orientation. RHS is an integral of a $1$ form. By definition of the exterior derivative, $df=f'(x)dx$. It is worth mentioning, however, that one does not derive FTS from Stokes theorem, but the other way around - the proof of Stokes theorem uses FTC.